# sizing memory for virtual ETL server - is paging recommended?

Tags: virtualization, memory, capacity-planning

I am working on the sizing for a virtual server to be used for Business Intelligence ETL processing.

We have an existing server from which I can observe the expected trend on the planned one - almost 80% RAM (of 8GB) is used on average and page file usage varies greately based on the batch job being processed.

Now going for a virtual server option - should I estimate more than the existing RAM like 12GB or so and disable paging? Since I'm afraid excessive paging will cause performance issues on a virtualised server, compared to the same amount of paging being done on a normal machine.

Is it recommended to set lower paging space and ask for more memory allocated on the virtual server, if there is chance of excessive paging  -since the application is a data crunching one?

Comment: What virtualization hypervisor technology are you planning to use?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only assume at the moment it is VSphere, this part is handled by another team. Does the platform really make a difference in the sizing decision?

Comment: Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: Update: the plan is dropped because there was an opinion that use of a VM for ETL could cause performance issues due to high data input/output operations.

Comment: That's unfortunate. We've evolved to the point where virtualized systems can run with little or negligible performance impact. This all depends on design, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would plan for the amount of RAM you really need, plus some... Say 16GB. In the example of VMware, there is a swap file created per VM, but  the system behavior when RAM is exhausted depends on the underlying hardware and the manner in which the host/cluster was configured.

You didn't specify the operating system in use either, but don't disable paging/swap.

The other benefit of going virtual... it is trivial to adjust the RAM allocation if there are problems down the line.